# How to enter values in a list using tokens = user_input.split()?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm taking an intro Python course and working through an assignment focused on lists and loops. Any help/direction on my code would be greatly appreciated. This is the code I have written so far (which comes back with syntax errors):

```
def print_scores(scores):
 for score in scores:
  print(str(score), end = " ")
  print("\n")

scores = [1 2 3 4 5]
while True:
 num = int(input('Input a score (-99 terminates)'))
 print([score for score in re.split(r'1','2','3','4','5' if score)
 if num == -99:
  break
 scores.append(num)
print_scores(scores)
```

Here are the directions from my assignment: 
You will enter all the scores in one line separated by a space and once done,
press Enter.
If you look at 8.3.2 you have this line (shown below) after calling the input() function.
tokens = user_input.split()
The split() function separates values into different values and placed it into tokens. You can use this same code in your program but note in next lines, it appends each value to a list called nums.
In our example, you will add values to your scores list.
Again, you will call the print_scores() function to print your list hence showthat your input of scores works.

Comment: Syntax error,use scores = [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: It would probably be very helpful to use an editor that can validate your code and also format it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code.

```
def print_scores(scores):
    for score in scores:
        print(str(score), end = " ")
        print("\n")

scores = [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5]
while True:
      num = int(input('Input a score (-99 terminates)'))
      print([score for score in scores])
      if num == -99:
         break
      scores.append(num)
print_scores(scores)
```

This code works perfectly in python3. If you want to use it in python2,replace the statement `print(str(score), end = " ")`

with

`print(str(score))`